# What is the fastest computational algorithm to find a monochromatic $K_{10}$ in a complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, computational-geometry

If I have an adjacency matrix like this (for example):
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 &1& 2& 2& 0& 1\\
 0 &0 &2 &2 &2 &1\\
 2 &2 &2 &2 &1 &2\\
 2 &2 &2 &0 &2 &2\\
 0 &1 &2 &2 &0 &1\\
 1 &1 &2 &2 &1 &0\end{bmatrix}$$

0 = connections
1 = red edge
2 = blue edge

Then how would I go about verifying if there is a monochromatic $K_{10}$ in it?
Note: I will have to apply it to very large graphs.

I would like an algorithm, but if anyone has a python library or a framework in another language which is able to verify this let me know please.

Comment: Do 0, 1, and 2 indicate colors?  Should the adjacency matrix be symmetric, or is your graph directed?

Comment: 0 means no connection, 1 means red edge, 2 means blue edge. Symmetric. Sorry for that, I'll clarify it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split into two graphs (red and blue), and independently look for a maximum clique in each, stopping whenever you reach $10$ in either graph.

As a preprocessing step in each graph, you can recursively remove any nodes with degree $<9$.

See [Solving the maximum clique and vertex coloring
problems on very large sparse networks](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cebc/4d29a5de8c72991b3d53a9e75f68f904ef87.pdf).

Comment: So asking in a, for example, red only subgraph, for each vertex's connections, then the connected vertices' connections and so on, each time verifying if all of them are connected to each other mutually until I find 10 mutually connecting vertices. Would that work well?

Comment: Note that this is NP-complete for arbitrary values of '10', and may be intractible even in the specific case for huge graphs; see e.g. [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.4391&rep=rep1&type=pdf#:~:text=Clique%20and%20dominating%20set%20are%20classical%20problems%20of%20complexity%20theory.&text=A%20parameter%2D%20ized%20problem%20is,case%20is%20independent%20from%20p.). I'm not actually sure if the original problem is NP-complete or not, though I would presume so.

Comment: If $10$ is kept constant, brute-force search is a polynomial-time algorithm because $n \choose 10$ is a polynomial in $n$.  On the other hand, it's  not a very nice polynomial.  In a practical problem, I might try tabu search, simulated annealing or a genetic algorithm.